# Unix-esque partial-file-locking mechanism

Tags: filesystems, lock

Linux and AFAIK most unixes expose the `flock` syscall for mandatory file-locking. My experience is admittedly limited with this, however am informed that it is kernel-enforced on the entire resource. But what if I wanted to only lock a part of a file mandatorily, such that read/writes to this resource are permitted, as long as they don't cross a particular boundary or stop reading once it reaches an outer bound of the locked region. Is this possible?

### Edit: Possible Implementation

A possibility for advisory partial locking may be via MMaped regions, where the memory is mapped into each reader's address-space, on the condition that the requested region does not hold a lock. This would be implemented entirely in user-space, and thus loses the advantages of kernel-enforced locking, but would certainly work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can acquire partial lock using the the [`fcntl(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) system call by the `F_SETLK`, `F_SETLKW`, or `F_GETLK` command macros, and providing the partial area to be locked through a an `flock` structure provided as the third argument.

> `F_SETLK`, `F_SETLKW`, and `F_GETLK` are used to acquire, release, and test
> for the existence of record locks (also known as byte-range,
> file-segment, or file-region locks).  The third argument, lock, is a
> pointer to a structure that has at least the following fields (in
> unspecified order).
>
> ```
> struct flock {
>     ...
>     short l_type;    /* Type of lock: F_RDLCK,
>                         F_WRLCK, F_UNLCK */
>     short l_whence;  /* How to interpret l_start:
>                         SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, SEEK_END */
>     off_t l_start;   /* Starting offset for lock */
>     off_t l_len;     /* Number of bytes to lock */
>     pid_t l_pid;     /* PID of process blocking our lock
>                         (set by F_GETLK and F_OFD_GETLK) */
>     ...
> };
> ```
>
> **The `l_whence`, `l_start`, and `l_len` fields of this structure specify the
> range of bytes we wish to lock.**  Bytes past the end of the file may be
> locked, but not bytes before the start of the file.